# Mono.block() throwing InvocationTargetException

Tags: kotlin, webclient, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I'm doing a WebClient get call that returns a Mono, which succeeds. But I'm trying to get at the String by doing a block() on the Mono. As a result, I get the exception throw.

This is the code I'm calling:

```
    val responseBody = webClient.get()
        .uri("/some-uri")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .exchangeToMono { response -> handleResponse(response) }
        .log()
        .block()
```

The response handler looks like:

```
fun handleResponse(response: ClientResponse): Mono<String> {
    if (response.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
        return response.bodyToMono(String::class.java)
    }
    else if (response.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
        // Handle client errors (e.g., 404 Not Found)
        return Mono.error(RuntimeException("Response not found"));
    }
    else if (response.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
        // Handle server errors (e.g., 500 Internal Server Error)
        return Mono.error(RuntimeException("Server error"));
    }
    else {
        // Handle other status codes as needed
        return Mono.error(RuntimeException("Unexpected error"));
    }
}
```

If I take out the block(), it works, but I need to convert the String to my custom complex object with lists of different classes.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace as well?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.
The firts and the prefered one is not to block.

```kotlin
return webClient.get()
    .uri("/some-uri")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .exchangeToMono { handleResponse(it) }
    .map { doSthWithIt(it) }
    .log()
```

Where inside `doSthWithIt` you can take what is inside the response, update the entity, send it over kafka, convert the String to your custom complex object with the lists of different classes, whatever. The point is do not block here.

Second option is to block and use `Schedulers.boundedElastic` ([doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking)):

```
return Mono.fromCallable {
    val response = webClient.get()
        .uri("/some-uri")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .exchangeToMono { handleResponse(it) }
        .block()
    
        doSthWithIt(response)
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
}
```

I do mostly java, so there may be some small syntax mismatches, but you get the idea.

A few words of explanation: you get the exception because you block. The whole point of reactive libraries is to not block, hence such blocking calls are detected and signalized with the exception. Project reactor also has integrated [BlockHound](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound) which prevents from blocking operations even more extensively.